# WPF keep UIElement centered on the visible area displayed by a scrollviewer

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, center, contentcontrol

I'd like to implement a Panel aware of it's visible area, centering it's content on the visibile area, even as the user scrolls to see more content.

Here is an example of the wanted behaviour that I've done on winform by overriding OnDraw
[image: If all visible : center]

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnDraw(graphics As GraphicsCache, area As RectangleF)
    brush = graphics.BrushsCache.GetBrush(ForeColor)
    Dim r = RectangleF.Intersect(graphics.Graphics.ClipBounds, area)
    graphics.Graphics.DrawString(Value, Font, brush, r, StringFormat)
End Sub
```

[image]

I tried to inherit from panel and override some events like ArrangeOverride, but they don't seem to fire when I place it in a ScrollViewer.

I've got the impression that I should stay away as much as possible from OnRender in WPF, so is there a way to achieve the desired effect ?

EDIT :

To clarify, in the **image below**, there is more than enough space to display *August* and *November* but the grid/border/canvas, containing the *Textblock*, is not centering it on the *visible area*
[image]

Comment: Why not put a Panel (e.g. a Grid) with a TextBlock on top of the ScrollViewer?

Comment: @Clemens Well, if I put a textblock with textAlignement in a Grid, it works fine _when the grid is fully visible_ when lets say half of the grid is clipped by the scrollviewer, the textblock is half visible...
but maybe I don't understand what you mean by **on top** ?

Comment: If you already subclassed a panel, you should also need to implement IScrollInfo to address "don't seem to fire when I place it in a Scroll..." issue. If you do that, you are including the scrolling events into layout mechanism of WPF panel. And of course, add the routines to achieve the goal.

Comment: @tgpdyk what I don't understand (I tried de IScrolInfo interface), is that a UIElement inside a ScrollViewer wont even call the OnRender sub when I scroll. I guess I'd need to rerender the object to get the effect I want.

Comment: You should put that on the OnArrange of Textblock's panel not on Onrender. Yes, its tedious.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a Panel with a TextBlock on top of the ScrollViewer:

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        ...
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, World."
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: ok but I guess this defeats the purpose of having a scrollviewer. I've edited my question to clarify.